# Static method requires that 'NSDictionary' conform to 'Encodable'

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, http

I am trying to make a http request function for calling an API I want to use. I keep getting the error that NSDictionary needs to conform to Encodable but in the initializations before the call Ive already made it encodable.

What am I doing wrong?

Error message

*Static method 'apiRequest(method:params:url:authToken:)' requires that 'NSDictionary' conform to 'Encodable'*

Below is the initialization for the API request parameters.

```
 private struct APIBody<CallParams: Encodable>: Encodable {
        var method: String
        var params: CallParams
        var jsonrpc = "2.0"
        var id = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    }

    private static let bodyEncoder: JSONEncoder = {
        let e = JSONEncoder()
        e.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
        return e
    }()
```

Below is the initialization for the API request to be sent.

```
private static func apiRequest<Params: Encodable>(
        method: String,
        params: Params,
        url: URL,
        authToken: String?
    ) throws -> URLRequest {
        let body = APIBody(method: method, params: params)

        var req = URLRequest(url: url)
        req.httpMethod = "POST"
        do {
            req.httpBody = try bodyEncoder.encode(body)
        } catch let e {
            assertionFailure("API encoding error: \(e)")
            throw e
        }
        req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        if let authToken = authToken, !authToken.isBlank {
            req.addValue(authToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Lbry-Auth-Token")
        }
        return req
    }
```

Below is the final call to the API where I get the error.

```
static func apiCall(
        method: String,
        params: [String: Any],
        connectionString: String,
        authToken: String? = nil,
        completion: @escaping ([String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void
    ) {
        let req: URLRequest
        do {
            req = try apiRequest( //<-- Error throws on this Line *********************
                method: method,
                params: params as NSDictionary,
                url: URL(string: connectionString)!,
                authToken: authToken
            )
        } catch let e {
            completion(nil, e)
            return
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // handle error
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            do {
                Log.verboseJSON.logIfEnabled(.debug, "Response to `\(method)`: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)")

                let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                if response?["result"] != nil {
                    completion(response, nil)
                } else {
                    if response?["error"] == nil, response?["result"] == nil {
                        completion(nil, nil)
                    } else if response?["error"] as? String != nil {
                        completion(nil, LbryApiResponseError(response?["error"] as! String))
                    } else if let errorJson = response?["error"] as? [String: Any] {
                        completion(nil, LbryApiResponseError(errorJson["message"] as! String))
                    } else {
                        completion(nil, LbryApiResponseError("unknown api error"))
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure there will be a better way using a `Codable` struct

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native Dictionary.